# How to optimize data decompression and conversion time? Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, data-conversion

I am working on a project, it reads data(**24bits** per sample) from binary files, decompress it to **32bits** and convert it **signed int**.
I have this function for the decompress and convert tasks, and it causes wasting a lot of time in the project for huge data.

```
signed int convertedSample(QByteArray samp){
QString sample = QString(samp.toHex() + "00");
bool ok;
signed int decimalSample = sample.toInt(&ok, 16);
return decimalSample;
}
```

To  read data from files and store it, I do:

```
while(!file.atEnd()){
QByteArray chunkSamples = file.read(chunkSize);// chunkSize here is the size of 1 million of samples
for (int i = 0; i < chunkSamples.size() ; i++){
QByteArray samp = chunkSamples.mid(i * 3, 3); // 24bits
buffer.append(convertedSample(samp)); // buffer is a QVector of int
}
```

Any help to make it faster ?

Comment: If you want to read three bytes, and store them in a 32-bit `int` value. Just read the three bytes, and use bitwise shifting and OR to combine the individual bytes into an  (*unsigned*) `int`. Don't go through strings, that will always be slow.

Comment: With that said, reading from files isn't very often realtime-sensitive so why do you need to "optimize" it? What are your requirements and limitations in regards to this? And just as [`while (!stream.eof())` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons), so is `while(!file.atEnd())`.

Comment: thanks @Someprogrammerdude , so using strings causes the slow here. how I can do the shifting and combine here from `QBytearray` to `unsigned int`  ?

Comment: Also avoid the `QByteArray::mid` call. It will create a useless temporary object. Access directly the bytes in `chunkSamples`.

Comment: Please take out a pen and some paper. Draw a box, divided into four parts. That represents the resulting 32-bit integer. Add labels on the divisions and ends, like `0`, `8`, `16`, `24` and `32`. Now to get one byte into the first part, from `0` to `7`, how much do you need to shift it? Then from `8` to `15`, how much do you need to shift it? And so on. The answer is already in the numbers you have written down. :)

Comment: Oh and remember that bits are numbered in the reverse order, so `32` should be on the left side, and `0` on the right. That will also tell you the shift-direction you need to use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I tried this `signed int test = samp.toHex().toInt(&ok, 16) << 8;` that's a correct I guess ?

Comment: That is still a useless round-trip to and from a string. You can call `toInt` directly on the QByteArray.

Comment: That's still using strings as an intermediate. And don't make much sense. Instead use `samp[0] | (samp[1] << 8) | (samp[2] << 16)` (depending on *byte order*). Assuming you did the pen-and-paper exercise I mentioned above, it should be very easy to see how it fits.

Comment: yes thank you @Someprogrammerdude, I got it and now it works faster ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guys in the comments, I've made some improvements over time. I avoided using strings for the conversion because it seems that using strings is always slow and replaced it with using bitwise shift and OR to combine the individual bytes into `int`.

I replaced this code:

```
QString sample = QString(samp.toHex() + "00");
bool ok;
int decimalSample = sample.toInt(&ok, 16);
```

with :

```
int32_t decimalSample = ((samp[0] << 24) | ((samp[1] << 16) & 0xFF0000) | ((samp[2] << 8) & 0xFF00));
     if(samp[0] & 0x80){
          decimalSample = - ((~decimalSample + 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF);
     }
```

Comment: Did those changes speed the process up sufficiently?

Comment: well, in my case I have 4 files of 4.2GB and this reduces all the process time from 2071 seconds to 737 seconds.